# Apache error log not showing full path of 404 failures

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, log-files, http-status-code-404

If I have a working path like

`/gallery/landscapes`

and I try to access this inexistent url:

`/gallery/landscapes/whatever`

I see the 404 error in my browser but the apache log says that I had an error at this location:

`/gallery/landscapes`

truncating the full url where error occured, I was expecting to see the full path that I tried. 
My urls are made `clean` with htaccess rewrite rules (if it matters). 
What can cause this ?

**Edit:** actually if user tries `/gallery/landscapes/whatever` the request is recieved by my file browse_category.php , this file checks the path and triggers a 404 error if inexistent, this causes the client to see 404 page and headers but I was expecting this 404 to also be saved in apache error_log.

So this is normal or is there a way to save this 404 in apache error_log ?

My .htaccess looks like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)(/)?$ category.php?cat_url_string=$1 [QSA]
```

And if it cannot find the requested path/category/file, it includes my **404.php file** that looks like this:

```
<?php  

header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
header("Status: 404 Not Found");

echo "Error - Page not found";

?>
```

Comment: Probably the .htaccess rewrites. Try (temporarily) disabling them and see what happens.

Comment: I edited my question to include some important details.

Comment: Can u please post your .htaccess (sorry but i cant comment until 50 rep)

Comment: I edited and included .htaccess and my 404 error page.